# How to show boot messages instead of logo animations in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, boot, windows-8.1, freeze

Is it possible to see boot messages on Windows boot instead of logo animations?

Like it happens with Linux boot.

I want to know what is happening if boot hangs.

Comment: Never saw something like this in Windows. You cold check the event log though.

Comment: try NoGuiBoot option in msconfig.exe